# Store users in context or somewhere else?

Tags: go

I am having a hard time finding out if I am thinking about things in the best way. I want to know what to do with a user after they have been authenticated through some type of middleware, either `BasicAuth` or `JWT`.

Should I store all the relevant user fields in the context as a value? If I store them in the context then do I need a special function to pull them out? (which would use a user defined contextKey type to retrieve and convert its type back to the proper struct)

I can come up with something that works, but IDK if it is the most reasonable way to go about it.

Comment: Storing user info in context under a customly-typed key sounds perfectly reasonable.

Comment: then how would you see pulling the user out? by a function call?

Comment: Yes. With functions like `withUser(ctx, user)` and `userFromCtx(ctx)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) is specifically for request scoped variables, among other things.  (Notice, per request, so not suitable for storing data you mean to access between requests; for that you should consider some sort of session mechanism)

the `context.Value(key interface{}) interface{}` interface function is how you retrieve values back out of the context.